# Using multer library in backend and hosting it to cyclic.sh gives EROFS error

Tags: node.js, express, multer, cyclic

I have used multer in my project to get audio files from the frontend application and store that audio file inside uploads folder present in the root directory of my Node.js application.

After hosting the server in cyclic.sh it's giving me error
[image: Error: EROFS]

I read cyclic.sh is read only and to store files we need S3 AWS bucket provided by cyclic.sh and using @cyclic.sh/s3fs package but I cant figure out how to solve my problem using this package.

I changed my fs the way mentioned in
https://github.com/cyclic-software/s3fs but it doesn't work.

How could I store the files in uploads folder using this package or by any other method?

Comment: Probably you have to refactor your code, using tmp dir

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how to use it.

Comment: Files need to persist on server? If so, tmp dir doesn’t help. Put relevant code, I can help to adapt it  for other persistent stores

Comment: I am using createReadStream() on the file inside uploads folder which is sent as body for an API call. After that the file is deleted from the upload folder using fs.unlinkAsync

Comment: Ok, but if you don’t post your code, nobody can help you! We cannot write from scratch your app…